# Dropbox photos deleted

Tags: dropbox

On my HTC EVO, all of my photos from the gallery suddenly moved to Dropbox. They are no longer in my gallery nor my SD card. If I unlink Dropbox from my phone, will my photos be deleted or will they move back to my gallery?

Comment: That's... odd. It shouldn't move/delete any of your photos.

Comment: Has Dropbox been linked for a long time already, or did you just install and link it today? and then it deleted your photos in the gallery?

Answer (score 1):

I actually had the same problem recently. It might be one of those, "It's a feature, not a bug" things. I had my Dropbox associated with my desktop computer. When I deleted a folder of pictures from my computer, it deleted those pictures from my dropbox all together.

This seems like quite a mistake, as deleting a local copy should not delete the remote copy on Dropbox.

You should be able to restore your deletions on the Dropbox website. I was able to recover everything I deleted. It doesn't actually delete your items for a long time (scary).